# jquery addclass when there is content on body

Tags: jquery, html, css

if body load text 'added to your shopping cart.' need to jquery addClass on div #header-cart

```
<span> added to your shopping cart.</span>
```

[image: Image describing the intent]

need to addClass and remove class after some 5 sec.

Comment: What have you tried, what went wrong, where did you get stuck? Also: if the text is in the `<body>` you want to add a class to which `<div>`?

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help

Comment: wtf is wrong with you guys... downvote because of HAT-event ?!?!

Comment: please check this link  http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b8447bfcc

Comment: @Dwza - no, likely because of this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @SW4 so the poster has his first post and is obviously not familier with the posting rulses... still no reason for me to hate like this... I saw even worse questions where people explaind SOF rules in comments and helped him to find into SOF. People in here are getting very selfish! Whats actually very sad. In germany there is proverb for this that's called: (translated) "There has never been a master that fellt from heaven"

Comment: @Dwza - I am not saying anything one way or another, just attempting to provide an answer, and hopefully some direction to the OP as to why they may have attracted negative attention.

Comment: @SW4 :) ok, but my comment above may be a incentive for devoters to think about what to do on "bad" posts

Comment: sorry guy. i m new here and don't know about jquery.  i'm able to do my best to follow rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //text you looking for
    var sText     = " added to your shopping cart.";
    //target element
    var target    = "#header-cart";
    //class you may want to add
    var tempClass = "skip-active";

    //check if element (span) exists that contains the searched text
    if($("span:contains('" + sText + "')").length > 0){
       //if found, add a class to this element with timeout/delay
       $( target ).addClass( tempClass );
       setTimeout(function() { 
           $( target ).removeClass( tempClass );
       }, 5000);
    }
});
```

See this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/1yz7n2ne/)**

Comment: thank you but i really don't know where to add my class i need to add class $( "#header-cart" ).addClass( "skip-active" );

Comment: @RawiRai i updated my post, this should be what you are looking for. Here you can simply add parameter to the top vars and handle everything :)

Comment: thank you but removeclass not working.

Comment: @RawiRai than try to replace `this` with `target`

Comment: i changed to target but still no luck.

Comment: What about this way I edited the post

Comment: Hi @dwza need help. please check this link http://awesomescreenshot.com/06344xyacf   i used same code but i need only parent li

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to execute any function you want when you add something in cart (as you say that this text gets inserted when user adds a product), and not trying to catch if some text was inserted into DOM.

So, let's say user clicks on `#add-to-cart` button to add a product:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-to-cart', function() {
    $('body').addClass('yourClass').setTimeout(function() { 
       $('body').removeClass('yourClass');
    }, 5000);
    // place any other code
});
```

If you still want to check for the specific text, you have to perform this check every time an event fires (on page load? on a button click?):

```
// This will work only if you refresh the page and the text appears in the specific span on load
$(window).load(function() {
    var span = $('li.success-msg span').text();
    if (span.indexOf('added to your shopping cart') >=0) {
       // perform your actions
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you it works no i need to removeclass after 5sec please help edit below code  $j( "#header-cart" ).addClass( "skip-active" ); ----------------------------------- here is full code ----------------------------$j(window).load(function() {
    var span = $j('li.success-msg span').text();
    if (span.indexOf('added to your shopping cart') >=0) {
       $j( "#header-cart" ).addClass( "skip-active" );
    }
});
-------------------------------- sorry guys i m new and i don't know anything about rules and code :) place -------